# WPF validation showing from different layers

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I am trying to build a MDI UI in WPF.

I have tried MdiContainer and WPFMDI but I have an issue in both cases. If I have a usercontrol with validation showing red borders, and another user control is shown on top of it, the red border from behind is shown.

I have shown the behavior at https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/workitem/13413 and https://mdicontainer.codeplex.com/discussions/644330

Since the same issue happen in both library, is there something WPF-related?

Any idea on how to fix it?

**Since it seems a complex task, any ideas on how to build MDI UI using WPF that would work with validation?**

Comment: I have created a sample recreating the issue (which is using WPFMDI) available from [link](http://www.emoreau.com/ftpfiles/DemoIDataErrorInfo.rar)

Comment: trying to add an image: ![link](http://www.emoreau.com/images/mdichild.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue and it is not related to the WPFMDI component I am using.

The solution is to wrap your StackPanel or Grid containing the controls being validated into an  AdornerDecorator.

The solution was found at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B195328